# iOS alerts behavior is inconsistent with identical APNS messages

Tags: ios, notifications, push, amazon-sns

Server side guy here.

I'm sending the exact same APNS payload to the same device and I'm seeing different results:

1. Phone lights up, alert is shown
2. Phone lights up, no alert

As far as I can tell this is random. At times the phone will show the alert, at times it will not. But in all cases, the APNS message is the same.

Either scenario will happen at random. Despite my efforts, I cannot reproduce a pattern.

An APNS payload looks the same in both scenarios:

```
{
  "aps": {
    "alert": "Blah Blah Blah something useful happened",
    "badge": 0
  }
}
```

What I'm trying to figure out is, where does the issue lie? Is this an iOS client issue or is this a server side issue?

To this date, I've been able to reproduce the issue with the following push services:

- Amazon SNS
- Urban Airship
- Parse
- PushSharp

Does iOS do something with the notifs that I'm not aware of? Is this an APNS issue? Is the payload package messed up? Or is it an application issue?

Comment: Did this start happening just in recent hours? If yes, I think it's from Apple's side. My push notifications started to fail randomly and I haven't changed ANYTHING at server side. I am using ASP.NET/PushSharp to send pushes.

Comment: No, unfortunately, this has been happening for quite some time. I was using PushSharp and I switched to Amazon SNS thinking that SNS would solve the problem, but it didn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found the answer.

If the target device had a badge count greater than 0 and a notif with a badge count of 0 is sent, iOS clears all the notifs by the app. This results in a quick flash on the screen w/o a notif showing.

To reproduce, send this to a device to get the badge count up:

```
{
  "aps": {
    "alert": "this notif will show up",
    "badge": 2
  }
}
```

Then, send this payload and the notif won't show up:

```
{
  "aps": {
    "alert": "this notif will not show up",
    "badge": 0
  }
}
```

Apple has a quick line in their docs about the badge, "To remove the badge, set the value of this property to 0." This does more than remove the badge, but prevents the sending notif from showing up and clears any previous notifs that might still be unread.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW1